# Mongodb aggregate with joins with multiple keys

Tags: mongodb-query

I am using aggregate join as shown below:

```
 db.users.aggregate([{$lookup:
    {
        from: "userinfo",            
        localField: "userId",            
        foreignField: "userId",       
        as: "userres" }    
    }], function (err, info)
    {
        res.json(info);
    }
);
```

In the above code, can I add another condition for secondary collection?
Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately $lookup match uses only one field in source and external collection.
If you are really in need to have more complex WHERE clause -then the solution will be to add an extra computed field to both collection to match look-ups exactly as needed.

Comment: could you add tis info to you query directly?

Comment: was thinking about that - and to match $lookup we need an extra field to both collections, so userId should be transformed to something like : userId_canIUseThisInLookup . This is a kind of workaround of current limitation, but still a viable solution. Why in both collections? -> to have a match on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am not trying to match two collection's . I am looking for match the field with secondary collection. I'll explain my problem clearly:
                                                                                                  this is my primary collection "bags".which contains

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("568f43e08a9f71b70b22a694"),
            "bagNo" : "HBBN/00001/16",
            "category" : "Voluntary",
            "regNo" : "DNR/00001/16",
            "status": "Accepted"
    },
```

{
"_id" : ObjectId("568f4645fa0758af0e3fef26"),
        "bagNo" :"HBBN/00002/16",
        "category" : "Voluntary",
        "regNo" : "DNR/00002/16",
        "status": "Rejected"
},

{
"_id" : ObjectId("568f4645fa4546gygfef26"),
        "bagNo" : "HBBN/00003/16",
        "category" : "Voluntary",
        "regNo" : "DNR/00003/16",
        "status": "Accepted"
}

now my join collection "donor" contains

```
    {"donorType" : "H",
     "regNo" : "DNR/00001/16",
     "surName" : "pandey",
     "firstName" : "rakesh"},
```

{"donorType" : "C",
        "regNo" : "DNR/00002/16",
        "surName" : "pandey",
        "firstName" : "rakesh"                                                                                              },

{"donorType" : "C",
        "regNo" : "DNR/00003/16",
        "surName" : "pandey",
        "firstName" : "rakesh"                                                                                              }

from these two  collections i want to get the accepted bags data from bags collection which having 'donortype' as 'H'  in donor collection.Please let me know  if it is possible.explain with some example

Comment: are you going to execute this as a query or you have a pice of application, btw let's chat here - to discuss it http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues